# How to disable indexing in plone?

Tags: plone, zope

The data.fs is behaving weird and its size is getting increased everyday by 5-6% without much addition of content. I want to stop indexing.

I tried removing indexes from the portal_catalog but site started giving error.

Can anybody suggest how to stop indexing so that my disk space is not filled so fast.

Comment: i'm not sure indexing is the reason for your growing database. to be sure you'll have to mount the catalog to a separate database.
your application might write to zodb on read requests. try mounting the datatbase read only and accessing the site should work w/o errors.

Comment: There is not much documentation about such cases on the net. I found this one link: https://mail.zope.org/pipermail/zope/2004-May/149896.html which says disabling indexing can help as portal_catalog is getting bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0):

[collective.noindexing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.noindexing) might help. I'd try it on a copy of production.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying the first alternative given in the link you have mentioned.